# Remap "NUM ," to "NUM ." (German keyboard)

Tags: 16.04, keyboard, remapping

I am looking for an easy way to bind the `NUM ,` in the German keyboard layout to a `NUM .` in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. Is it possible within `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pc`?

obviously the key is key `key <KPDL>`

[image]

therefore, I already tried to edit `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pc` and insert:

```
key <KPDL> { [ '.', '.' ] };
```

I reconfigured with

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xkb-data
```

However, this did not work. Therefore my question is: how can i map `.` to the `NUM ,` key?